# Unable to Logout Completely From Web site Using Form Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, authorization, forms-authentication

I am using form authentication to authenticate and authorize the request in my website.

Here is the code for Login :

```
var objLogin = new LoginModel { Email = model.Email, Password = CommonMethod.Encryptdata(model.Password) };
var UserDetail = Users.LoginUser(objLogin); 
if (UserDetail.ErrorMessage == "SuccessLogin")
{
    var UserData = UserDetail.UserId + "," + UserDetail.UserRole + "," + UserDetail.Email + "," + UserDetail.FirstName + "," + UserDetail.LastName;
    DateTime expirydate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
    var Ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, UserDetail.Email, DateTime.Now, expirydate, true, UserData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(Ticket);
    var Cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
    Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);
    ViewBag.InActiveStatus = "";

    //Code for expiration
    if (Ticket.IsPersistent)
    {
        Cookie.Expires = Ticket.Expiration;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

I am using persistent cookie.

The method used to logout of the website contains following code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

Session.Abandon();
Session.Clear();
Session.RemoveAll();

string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
{
    Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
}

return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```

The Problem I am facing is after sign out I am able to surf Home controller 
Pages. I have implemented Authorize(Roles="user") on all home controller methods.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
public ActionResult Index()
```

But I am not able to surf pages from other controllers(other than home).e.g 
In Challenge Controller the following method :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
public ActionResult MyChallenges()
```

The problem gets solved when I forcefully clean the browsers cookies.But this is not recommended for the normal user from user experience point of view.

Please tell why this is happening ? Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Hi Stackoverflow Experts

I am still waiting for my answer !

Thanks
Imastu